# how to make the text box show the date directly without putting the cursor and tap in the keybaord

Tags: c#, textbox

please help me with this issue.
I'm using windows forms in C# and I have textbox that I want to display the date on it.
but its not working without putting the cursor on the text box and click on the keyboard after that the date is display. I want it to be display directly.

see the my code

```
        private void rdate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
            rdate.Text = d.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: It's wrong to put your code in textchange event in this case. You have to do it with a timer if you want it to be live.

Comment: It in general makes *very* little sense to display a date in a TextBox.  Using the TextChanged event makes even less sense.  Use a Label to display a date, a DateTimePicker to let the user select a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your Form Load event:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTime d = DateTime.Now; rdate.Text = d.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show time with Second-Level accurecy, You have to work with a `Timer` or a `BackGroundWorker`. Like this

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer T = new Timer() { Interval = 1000, Enabled=true };
        T.Tick += T_Tick;
        T_Tick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        textBox1.Text = d.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, You right, if you got your answer, don't forget the **UpVote** http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0):

Your code waits to the TextChanged event.
You should decide what event is most suitable for your goal.
Mostly it will be in the form constructor, and might be updated using a timer

Answer (score 0):

On the Form Load event assign you textbox with date string.

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```